# Why does the Java Extension Mechanism not check the classpath for an optional package implementing LocaleServiceProvider?

Tags: java, plugins, locale

I have created a maven project `L` and written a [Java extension (i.e. an optional package)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/) implementing (i.e. extending) the (abstract) service providers that implement (i.e. extend) [LocaleServiceProvider](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/spi/LocaleServiceProvider.html), to support a dialect (let's call it `xy`) that isn't normally supported by the JRE. (I do ***not*** want to use the CLDR extension that came with Java 8, even though I'm running 8.141.)

The project compiles, and produces a `jar` with a `META-INF/services` folder that contains the provider-configuration files in UTF-8 with the qualified provider class names being on a line that ends with a line feed (`\n`).

I have then declared a maven dependency in my project `P` on the locale project `L`, and I thought that that would work, because the tutorial [states](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/load.html)

> The extension framework makes use of the class-loading delegation
>   mechanism. When the runtime environment needs to load a new class for
>   an application, it looks for the class in the following locations, in
>   order:
>
> [...]
>
> 3. The class path: classes, including classes in JAR files,
>      on paths specified by the system property java.class.path. If a JAR
>      file on the class path has a manifest with the Class-Path attribute,
>      JAR files specified by the Class-Path attribute will be searched also.
>      By default, the java.class.path property's value is ., the current
>      directory. You can change the value by using the -classpath or -cp
>      command-line options, or setting the CLASSPATH environment variable.
>      The command-line options override the setting of the CLASSPATH
>      environment variable.

Maven puts all dependencies on the classpath, I believe.

Yet when I run my unit test in `P` (in IntelliJ; `L` is on the classpath), it fails:

```
@Test
public void xyLocalePresent() {
    Locale xy = new Locale("xy");
    assertEquals("P not on classpath", xy, com.example.l.Locales.XY); // access constant in my Locale project L; should be equals to locale defined here
    SimpleDateFormat df = (SimpleDateFormat) DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, xy);
    assertEquals("dd/MM/yy", df.toPattern()); // fails; L specifies the short date pattern as dd/MM/yy
}
```

I have to start it with `-Djava.locale.providers=SPI,JRE -Djava.ext.dirs=/path/to/project/L/target`. If I do that, it works, indicating that `L`'s service providers were loaded successfully (indicating the `jar`'s structure is ok).

NB: the Java 8 [technotes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/enhancements.8.html#cldr) say that the order `SPI,JRE` is the default.

Why, oh why does it not work when I just put `L` on the classpath? Why do I have to point to it explicitly?

**Update:** After going through the JavaDoc again, I just saw this (emphasis mine):

> Implementations of these locale sensitive services are packaged using
>   the Java Extension Mechanism as **installed** extensions.

That explains things. :(

**Is there any way to make this work** by just putting `L` on the classpath when `P` runs, i.e. **without having to install `L`** (or having to use `-D` system properties)? (`P` uses maven, Struts2 and Spring, if that helps...)

Answer (score 1):

In more complex applications, such as web servers (e.g. Tomcat), there are multiple ClassLoaders, so each WebApp served by the web server can be kept independent.

The extension mechanism is for extending the core Java functionality, i.e. features available globally within the running JVM (the web server). As such, they must be loaded by the System ClassLoader.

The standard way to add an extension to the code Java runtime, is to either

- add the Jar file to the `JRE_HOME/lib/ext` folder
- add extra folders to be searched by specifying the `java.ext.dirs` system property

You could also just add it to the Bootstrap ClassPath yourself, but that might cause problems if the Security Manager is activated. Not sure about that part. So it's best to do it the official way.

Note that the classpath defined by the `CLASSPATH` environment variable, or the `-cp` command-line option, does not define the Bootstrap ClassPath.

To learn more, read the Java documentation "[How Classes are Found](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html)".

Comment: Caveat: I get the impression the extension classloader has been removed in Java 9, which will be released in September.  See [JEP 220](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/220), https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8065702 and http://marxsoftware.blogspot.com/2017/01/jdk-9-is-end-of-road-for-some-features.html .

Comment: I assumed as much when I saw the [notice](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/extensions/extensions.html) in the tech notes, saying the mechanism was deprecated; also given the removal of applets and how the downloaded extension mechanism looks like it was implemented to support them. I also thought they probably hadn't looked at LocaleServiceProvider. I assume `CLDR` will be advertised as the replacement, but its èn_GB` formats short dates `dd/MM/yyyy` while `JRE`'s uses only `dd/MM/yy` - inconsistencies like that will cause wired and wonderful side effects when parsing. ;-)

Comment: I'll take that back; looks like what I want will become possible with [Java 9](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/spi/LocaleServiceProvider.html): "Implementations of these locale sensitive services can be made available by adding them to the application's class path." Yay! :D